# paypal dg flow lightbox no longer works

Tags: javascript, paypal

I've noticed today that my link that usually popups up a paypal light box for digital goods express payment has stopped working. The link was working as recently as the 2012/11/21, and I checked that the problem exists on a server that contains old code (that used to work), so I don't think that this is something that I have changed, but rather something that paypal has changed in their js files.

The code I use is exactly what is generated by the paypal wizard:

```
<!-- INFO: The post URL "checkout.java" is invoked when clicked on "Pay with PayPal" button.-->

<form action='checkout.java' METHOD='POST'>
    <input type='image' name='paypal_submit' id='paypal_submit'  src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Pay with PayPal'/>
</form>
....

<!-- Add Digital goods in-context experience. Ensure that this script is added before the closing of html body tag -->

<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>


<script>

    var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(
    {
        trigger: 'paypal_submit',
        expType: 'instant'
         //PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.
    });

</script>
```

Firstly, when the page now loads, there looks like there's some noise on an image named 'nameOnButton' (the 'image' contains the text 'su yi' with a few empty boxes) that the PP javascript must insert, as it is not in the HTML that I generate. Various examples on the web also have this spurious image. The HTML looks like:

```
<form action="/pay/dpSetCheckout/" method="GET" target="PPDGFrame">
        <input type="hidden" name="express">
        <input type="hidden" name="trackingNumber" value="UNg0000306">
        <span class="nameOnButton"><a href="javascript:"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/checkout/nameOnButton.gif"></a><br><input type="image" name="paypal_submit" id="paypal_submit" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif" border="0" align="top" alt="Pay with PayPal"></span>
      </form>

...

<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({
        trigger: 'paypal_submit',
        expType: 'instant' 
        //PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.
    });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the 'pay with paypal' button, the screen 'shades to grey', but the paypal popup never appears. After about 5 seconds the error message 'Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.' appears in the javascript console, most probably because the lightbox was not created. I don't think this is a back end/configuration problem, because if I open the 'pay with paypal' link in a new tab, it opens up fine.

I'm not quite sure where to start debubgging this (seeing that there aren't any javascript error messsages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a bug with Japanese and Chinese language fonts in recent PayPal release and it should be fixed soon

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in the PayPal release as looks to be working now. Unbelievable that PayPal would release without proper testing!